# Logger output needs to be flushed by console.writeline?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In the following console application (.Net core 2.0), the output of `_logger.LogInformation()`, `_logger.LogError()` in the `Run()` will not show.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();
    Task.Run(() => app.Run()).Wait();
    // Console.WriteLine("Test"); // _logger.Information() will not output unless uncommented
    // Console.ReadKey(); works too
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().AddDebug();

    services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory); 
    services.AddLogging(); 
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
    var myOptions = new MyOptions();
    configuration.GetSection("Settings").Bind(myOptions);
    services.AddSingleton(myOptions);
    services.AddTransient<Application>();
}

public class Application
{
    ILogger _logger;
    MyOptions _settings;

    public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, MyOptions settings)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Application start...");
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```